# Python selenium webdriver not consistently selecting element even though it's there

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing a web scraper to collect the src link from a source tag in an html file and add it to a list.

The site has a video nested under a load of divs, but all of the pages eventually come to:

```
<video type="video/mp4" poster="someimagelink" preload="metadata" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="somemp4link">
</video>
```

My current method is logging into the site, going to the page with the links to the video pages, going to each video page one by one and trying to find the source tag and adding it to the list.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# A bunch of log in and get list of video page links, which works fine

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
for i in range(3):
    browser.get(soup('a', {'class', 'subject__item'})[i]['href'])
    vsoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
    print(vsoup('source'))
    browser.get('pageWithVideoPages')

    # This doen't add to a list, it just goes to the video page,
    # tries to find the source tag and print it out.
    # Then go back to original page and start loop again.
```

What happens however is I get this:

```
[<source src="themp4link" type="video/mp4"></source>]
[]
[]
[]
```

So the first one works fine, then all the rest just return black lists...as if there was no source tag, but mannually checking the inspector reveals that there is a source tag there.

Repeating this, I now get:

```
[<source src="http://themp4link" type="video/mp4"></source>]
[]
[<source src="http://themp4link" type="video/mp4"></source>]
```

The site needed javascript enabled to load the content (which is why i'm using webdriver to do this)...could it be something to do with that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you waiting for that video element to load before you try to grab the attribute?  Please show us the code that is grabbing the desired info and storing it.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Ah yes that's it! `browser.get(soup('a', {'class', 'subject__item'})[i]['href'])
    vsoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
    print(vsoup('source'))` is the code that gets what I'm looking for...added `time.sleep(5)` and works perfectly! Thankyou! (If you repeat as an answer I'll accept this as the answer)...thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to wait for the web element you are looking for.  You should explore using WebDriverWait.